# How to use an object from another class

Tags: c++, oop

I have two classes; one called `Date` and the other is `University`. `Date` class has two overloaded operators: `operator<<` and `operator>>` to take in the data and print them out.

```
Date.h

#ifndef DATE_H_
#define DATE_H_

#include <iostream>
#include "University.h"
using namespace std;

class Date {
public:
Date(); // constructor
void setDate( int d, int m, int y ); // set day, month, year
friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, Date & x); // print date format "month dd, yyyy (example: January 11, 2013)
friend istream & operator>>(istream & In, Date & x); // to read date
private:
int day; 
int month; 
int year; // 
};
#endif

Date.CPP
#include <iostream>
#include "Date.h"
#include "University.h"
using namespace std;



Date::Date()
{}


void Date::setDate( int d, int m, int y )
{
    day=d;
    month=m;
    year=y;
}




ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, Date & x)
{
    out<< x.month << "/" << x.day << "/" << x.year ;
    return out;
}

istream & operator>>(istream & in, Date & x)
{
    in>> x.day >> x.month >> x.year ;
    return in;
}
```

The `University` class has an object of type `Date` called `establishDate` and I must use this to print out the *date* along with the *university name* and *location*.

Here's class `University`:

```
// University.h

class University {
public:
    University (); // constructor
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, University & x); // print the university data
    friend istream & operator>>(istream & in, University & x); // to read university data
private:
    const static string uname; 
    string location;
    Date establishDate; 
};

const string uname = "London University";
```

How do I use the object `establishDate`?

Comment: Did you try `cout << establishedData` for example?

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: I don't think it's as simple as that Shahbaz
and Konrad I apologies but am new here :P

Comment: Also I can't simply use cout because it's private right ?

Comment: @user3125670, do you have any idea as to why you are using the `friend` keyword, there?

Comment: I included Date class please look

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something such as below:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, University & x)
{
   out<< x.uname << " in " << x.location << " has been established in: " << x.establishDate.month << "/" << x.establishDate.day << "/" << x.establishDate.year ;
   return out;
}
```

This works, because the operator is a friend and thus has access to the private members.

Comment: It says (month , day , year) are inaccessible , guys I know these are stupid questions but I am self learning and I might be missing some stuff , anyways those variables are private in Date class , and this operator is in University class

Comment: Ah ah my bad. Use << establisheddate instead or add public get functions for your date class